# Speech Synthesis API isn't working in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, web, browser, client-side, speech-synthesis

I'm trying to use the SpeechSynthesis API for my website, but it turns out that the same code that works on a desktop browser, doesn't work on a mobile browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>prueba</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="play()">Play</button>
  <script>
    function play() {
      if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
        console.log("The API is installed");
        var ssu = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("hello world");
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(ssu);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tested it on a Huawei P10 with Chrome, iPhone X with Safari, and a Moto G5 with Chrome. None of these work. Does it work on your phones? Do you know how to fix it? Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

After deleting the history and cleaning cache, it works on Android devices. But it still doesn't work on iPhones (I've tested it on Iphone X and Iphone 6, before and after deleting the history and cache).

Comment: The example you provided works fine on my Android device. Huwawei Y6 Pro (Chrome 67.0) Try this js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/230kh1gf/1/

Comment: I've just tested the jsfiddle link in both an iPhone X (Safari) and Moto G5 (Chrome 66.0), but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Just to check, You do have the media volumes at non-mute levels right?

Comment: Hahah yes, at the max, in fact.

Comment: nipuna777's fiddle works on iOS and Android, but note that on iOS Safari, you need to make sure the soft mute button is not activated to hear anyting.  iOS chrome doesn't have this restriction. There are lots of issues with mobile implementations of speechSynthesis (see https://talkrapp.com/speechSynthesis.html), but this code is fine.

Comment: ON FIREFOX MOBILE SPEECH SYNTHESIS WORKS even without calling cancel() before speak()